# Batch File to acess a directory and execute a python script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file to execute python scripts in different directories, something like that:

```
C:\Test
   |---Test1\example.py
   |---Test2\example.py
   |---Test3\example.py
|--run.bat
```

I have multiple folders inside Test, 'Test1', 'Test2' and 'Test3', I need to run them simultaneously with different command prompts, but i'dont know how to do that, I got something like that:

```
@echo off
set back=%cd%
for /d %%i in (C:\Test\*) do (
start
cd "%%i"
python example.py
pause
cd %back%
)
```

But it only runs a script and goes back to the home directory, so I noticed, I believe it is running for only the first directory, any suggestions for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You want to run a batch file that will open multiple cmd prompts to run simultaneously your scripts?

Comment: Yeah, exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the keyword `start` before the command to execute it in a new prompt.

to open the python interactive shell in a new cmd prompt.

```
start python
```

to execute a python file `new.py` in a new cmd prompt.

```
start python new.py
```

**EDIT:**

here is the complete code to execute the scripts on different cmd prompts

```
@echo off
echo "this is the main batch script"
for /d %%i in (C:\Test\*) do (
start python "%%i\example.py"
)
pause
```

Comment: I got something like that look: @echo off set back=%cd% for /d %%i in (C:\Test*) do ( start cd "%%i" python example.py pause cd %back% ) but he doesn't acess the next folder, and execute the script.

Comment: to make your python scripts not close by itself  add a line input() at the end of your python file which will make the prompt wait, a quick easy fix

Answer (score 1):

When you need to run things simultaneously, you can't do this in a batch file: a batch file is executing commands in sequence, not simultaneously.

I'd propose you to add those things to the task scheduler, and let all things start at the same moment.